# Argument 'PricesController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have looked at a lot of examples related to setting up the app, and everything I'm doing seems correct but I'm still getting the error above.  Here's my setup.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="homePricesApp">
  <head>
    <script src="libs/angular.1.0.8.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body >
      <div data-ng-controller="PricesController"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module("homePricesApp", []);

app.controller('PricesController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

} ]);
```

So what I'm doing is creating a new homePricesApp module, and when the page is loaded, because I have `data-ng-app="homePricesApp"`, it initializes the homePricesApp module.  I then create the controller. But when the page loads I get the error:

```
"Argument 'PricesController' is not a function, got undefined".
```

Any ideas would be greatly welcome.

**UPDATE**

After much reading I came across the idea of manually bootstrapping the app using the code below, which worked, as in it now hits my controller, but the error is being thrown by angular.js before it hits the controller code.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('pricesResults'), ['homePricesApp']);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that controllers.js is loaded by the HTML page?

Comment: Seems to work [just fine](http://jsbin.com/eCOpalu/1/edit).

Comment: Yeah, controllers.js is loaded by the page just after angular.

Comment: I'd bring this up in chrome developers tools (or equivalent) and make sure controller.js is really loaded (you can check in the network tab to see if it loaded or has a 404 error).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

Your angular is loaded correctly? try this
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js

Comment: Yeah angular is loaded correctly because when I step through the code, it's fine with the line - var app = angular.module("homePricesApp", []); It's only after it's tried registering the controller that it throws the error.  Puzzled why it's fine for you guys but keeps throwing the error for me.